# Tailwind background image opacity transition

Tags: image, tailwind-css, opacity

In my web page I'm trying to change give a div a background image using `bg-[url('path')]` I have a React component that has an array of objects, some of these objects have the property called `color` which I'm using to change the style of the container depending on the type of content. In this case I'm trying to pass the following Tailwind styles as props to my DesignGame component as `color` classes to be applied.

```css
hover:bg-opacity-100 bg-[url('path')] bg-opacity-0
```

```js
function DesignGame({GraphicDesign}) {
  const {image, alt, color} = GraphicDesign;

  return (
    <Link className={"project " + color}>
        <img src={image} alt={alt}/>
    </Link>
  )
}
```

The `.project` CSS class has the following Tailwind utility classes:

```css
flex items-center justify-center min-h-[20vh] border-[#ffffff] border-2 w-[1fr] duration-500 bg-cover bg-center transition-all
```

I'm trying to give the container a transition animation in which the background image opacity changes when the user hovers over the component, but for some reason it doesn't respond to the transition timing.

I have tried to use the `bg-opacity` utility class, but it shows the image as soon as the page loads and stays like that. I have read the Tailwind documentation, but I have not found a solution.

Comment: Background images aren't animatable in CSS (nor are there any Tailwind utilities to make them so).  You could add another element on top of the image with a solid color that matches your background and fade that out on hover.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know It couldn't be animated, sorry for the redaction of the issue, I'm still new to stackoverflow